# Why I am gatting getting Parcelable encountered IOException when try to pass an Interface object through intent

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass an Interface object through intent.

```
public interface ILockKeyConfig extends Serializable{
   public void onKeyConfigChage();
}

 // then I am doing in Activity A
 Intent intent = new Intent(LockScreenSettings.this,ButtonCustomization.class);
            ILockKeyConfig iLockKeyConfig = new ILockKeyConfig() {

                @Override
                public void onKeyConfigChage() {
                    System.out.println("onKeyConfigChage called");

                }
            };
            Object[] keConfig = {lockScreenKeyList.get(position),iLockKeyConfig};
            intent.putExtra("KeyConfigObj", keConfig);
            startActivity(intent);


//and in Activity B I am doing...
private void getIntentData() {
    Object[] KeyConfigObj = (Object[]) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("KeyConfigObj");
    keyConfig = (KeyConfig) KeyConfigObj[0];
    iLockKeyConfig = (ILockKeyConfig) KeyConfigObj[1];
}
```

but for the above code I am getting the following error:

> `06-27 15:18:04.648: E/AndroidRuntime(5483): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object

What is going wrong here?

Comment: The objects you pass through `Intent` must be either `Serializable` or `Parcelable`.

Comment: but I extends Serializable in my interface?

Comment: Oh I see. But your actual class is non static inner class so it cannot be deserialized anywhere else but within the class instance which has created it.

Comment: thanks , Tomasz now I got what I am doing wrong..its relay helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You either implement parcelable or put your serialized objecs into ArrayList. ArrayList implements Serializable and would accept as long as your arraylist have serializable objects.

```
putExtra(String name, Serializable value)
```

or

```
public Intent putExtra (String name, Parcelable[] value)
```